# How to highlight a specific x value with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=0
xval=[]
yval=[]
for i in range(0,1000):
    x=i
    xval.append(x)
    y=1-(0.99**x)
    yval.append(y)
plt.axhline(0.5, color='r')
plt.axvline(69, color='r')
plt.plot(xval,yval)
plt.show()
```

I want to highlight the 69 on the x-axis like this:
[image: example]

Does anyone know how to show a specific x value on the axis?

Comment: I swear it isn't intentional!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `xticks`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=0
xval=[]
yval=[]
for i in range(0,1000):
    x=i
    xval.append(x)
    y=1-(0.99**x)
    yval.append(y)
plt.axhline(0.5, color='r')
plt.axvline(69, color='r')
plt.plot(xval,yval)
plt.xticks([69],["Nice"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make it show aswell as the default ticks?

Comment: plt.xticks([69]+range(0,1000,200),["Nice"]+range(0,1000,200))